# Java threads : program design query

Tags: java

I have some Customer data which provides the shopping behaviour of different types of customers in a shop.

E.g. types of Customers could be:

```
cust1_young_male
cust2_young_female
cust3_adult_male
cust4_young_female
cust5_elderly_male
```

Type of transactions could be

```
buy_fruits
buy_beauty_products
buy_bakery_items
buy_vegetables
buy_toys
```

Finally, I have some probabilities like "young males buy fruits 12 times a month spending 5$ per transaction", "elderly females buy bakery items 15 times a month spending 3$ per transaction" and so on.

I want to create a program which will create threads to simulate a shopping scenario. Each thread will pick a type of customer and type of transaction and will hit database to save the transaction.

What is the right way to truly randomize thread creation and execution so that it matches the real world scenario where a shop can get any type of customer any time buying anything ?

Comment: What's wrong with (1) pick a random customer type, then (2) pick a random transaction type? "True randomness" is another topic entirely, as is simulating real-world data (which would definitely require statistics on said data and the simplest approach is just doing weighted randomness).

Comment: If you're trying to also randomise the actual number of items and dollar amount, you'll need to concretely specify the constraints there (otherwise the question is too broad / opinion-based), at which point the way to do it would likely be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

use Math.random to produce that behavior and create buckets as per your user group. 
For example : use random number to decide if current thread is for young male or elder female , Math.random() to decide.

Once it is decided : if young male is selected do Math.random again with 0-30 range and decide between two buckets 0-12 for buys , and 12-30 non buys.

Same way it can be done for other users as well.